# How to access child nodes by name in XML using DOM parser?

Tags: java, xml, domparser

I have an xml file in following format:

```
....
<ecs:Person>
     <ecs:abc>1234</ecs:abc>
     <ecs:def>9090</ecs:def>
</ecs:Person>
<ecs:Person>
     <ecs:def>1010</ecs:def>
</ecs:Person>
...
```

From above xml, we can understand that node "ecs:abc" is optional. I want to get value of "ecs:def" for all person. For that I was thinking to follow below approach:

```
....
int len = d.getElementsByTagName("ecs:Person").getLength();
for(int i=0;i < personLen;i++){
    print d.getElementsByTagName("ecs:Person").item(j).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent()
}
```

But as you can see, for second person node..as "ecs:abc" is not present so "ecs:def" will be at 0th position. So is there any way by which I can get the child nodes by Name not by position for respective "ecs:Person" node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 look for getElementsByTagName("ecs:Person")

```
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

NodeList nList = d.getElementsByTagName("ecs:Person");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) 
    {
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
       {
       Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
```

Dont use index 0, 1 , ...

2 inside each one, look for getElementsByTagName("ecs:def")

```
       // DO IT AGAIN: 
       eElement.getElementsByTagName("ecs:def");
```

Comment: Can you give proper syntax? Because for child node item's in eclipse i am not getting "getElementsByTagName" function

Comment: Thanks. It's working :) Thanks a lot for your help :)